# Blender Internal models in Eevee

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I've been using Blender Internal (Blender Render) for the past years, and since that's not in the latest version of Blender, I wanted to ask if there was a way to render out my old models in Eevee without having to manually edit them to function properly. My biggest problem is that the textures don't show up (some of them were generated procedurally).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. Blender internal and eevee are way too different to be cross compatible. Materials can only be converted manually by baking the property maps or recreating the textures and functions in the node editor. You are better off keeping the latest version of 2.79 for your old files rather than porting them to 2.8x.